# Modify code for javascript from php

Tags: javascript

I am using a series of check boxes all are with different name that is checkbox1....checkbox40. I am generating a series of sting with '1' and '0' that is if check box is checked than sting will be concatenated with '1' else it will be concatenated with '0'. I have successfully implemented idea for PHP but as now I am using Ajax I want to develop same code for java script. My PHP code for that is

```
if (isset($_POST[submit]))
{
for ($i=1; $i<41; $i++)
    {
    $walue = "restriction".$i;
    if(isset($_POST[$walue])) {$val .="1";} else {$val .="0";}
    }
}
echo "Equivalent String: ".$val."<p>";
```

for implementing it using Javascript I have called a function on submit event of form.

My form id is `theForm` and my checkboxes name is `restriction1....restriction40`. Please give me hint to implement the idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So.. something like this?

```
getCheckedString = function () {
    var chunks = [];
    var checkboxes = $("#theForm").children('input[type=checkbox]').each(function () {
        chunks[chunks.length] = $(this).is(':checked') ? '1' : '0';
    });
    return chunks.join('');
}
```

This will gather up all of the checkboxes in the order they are on the form, put a '1' or '0' in the array, then return the array joined into a string. It's not specific to a particular name, so if there are other checkboxes in the form let me know and I'll alter my answer.

Comment: Checkboxes are named as `restriction1....restriction40.` and form has id `theForm`

Answer (score 1):

If you have only named checkboxes, you would do:

```
function getCheckedString1() {
    var val = "";
    for (var i = 1; i <= 40; ++i) {
        var boxes = document.getElementsByName("restriction" + i); // returns an array
        if (boxes[0]) {
            val += boxes[0].checked ? "1" : "0";
        }
    }
    // alert(val);  
    return val;
}
```

However, it is easier and the usual praxis to identify the referenced HTML elements with ID's. So, you would enhance your HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="restriction1" id="restriction1" ...
<input type="checkbox" name="restriction2" id="restriction2" ...
```

and then use:

```
function getCheckedString2() {
    var val = "";
    for (var i = 1; i <= 40; ++i) {
        var box = document.getElementById("restriction" + i); // returns the unique element
        if (box) {
            val += box.checked ? "1" : "0";
        }
    }
    // alert(val);
    return val;
}
```